# Is there a service pack for Windows 2008 Web?

Tags: windows-server-2008, web, service-pack

I'd like to know if there is a version of recently issued service pack for Windows 7 / Windows 2008 that will work with Windows 2008 Web Edition 64-bit.

I tried to update it with the one for Windows 2008 64-bit, but it informed me that it's not suitable for this version of operating system . It's also not possible to find it with windows update.

Thanks in advance for Your help!

Comment: Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Don't you think this is something you should be asking Microsoft about?

Comment: Probably I should, but posting a question here allows me to get feedback sooner as You can see below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest service pack for **Windows Server 2008** (and Windows Vista) is service pack 2.

The latest service pack for **Windows Server 2008 R2** (and Windows 7) is service pack 1.

Both of them are for all system editions, including the Web one.